# Use tellraw to display a player death message about the player who died

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically, whenever someone dies, I say in chat:

`/tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"aqua","extra":[{"selector":"@p"},{"text":" has finally died"}]}`

The above command tells me whoever was closer to the command block when it was activated died. I currently have a scoreboard that tracks the deaths:

`/scoreboard players set @a hasDied 0`

And then removes them after the death message appears.

So I want to make something that basically looks like this:

`/tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"aqua","extra":[{"selector":"@p[score_hasDied_min=1]"},{"text":" has finally died"}]}`

How do I get the `@p[score_hasDied_min=1]` to work inside the tellraw command, or something similar?

(This is Minecraft v. 1.12.2)

Comment: That command works like you describe. What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't work in multiplayer in my case.

Comment: What happens in multiplayer? Error message, different effect, your computer explodes, ...?

Comment: It displays the player closer to the command blocks that he died, not the player that died farther away from the command blocks.

Comment: Do you kill multiple players in the same tick? Please give more detail about your problem, not just single sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, just follow my steps:

1. First make the scoreboard: `/scoreboard objectives add hadDied deathCount`
2. Place this in a repeating command block that is always active and is facin up with unconditional: `/testfor @a[score_hasDied_min=1]`
3. Place this in a chain command block with always active, condentional and facing up and place it over the repeating one: `/tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"aqua","extra":[{"selector":"@a[score_hasDied_min=1]"},{"text":" has finally died"}]}`
4. Place this chain command block over the last chain command block with the same configurations (always active, condentional and facing up): `/scoreboard players reset @a[score_hasDied_min=1] hasDied` And then it should work!

I have tried it online with my friends and it worked so hope it does for you to.

[image: This is how they should look like]

This is how they should look like